# Is a system, that is globally asymptotically stable for any constant input also input-to-state stable?

Tags: control-theory, nonlinear-system, stability-theory, nonlinear-dynamics, lyapunov-functions

I am referring to the ISS definition by Sontag of

${\displaystyle |x(t)|\leq \beta (|x_{0}|,t)+\gamma (\|u\|_{\infty }).}$

I understand that 0-GAS is a necessary condition for ISS. But is GAS for all constant u a sufficient condition?

*Update:*

For clarification, I mean the system is GAS for an arbitrary, but constant input u.

As of my understanding now, BIBO stability and 0-GAS are necessary for ISS. So the upper condition cannot be sufficient.
So the updated question is:

Is a system, that is BIBO stable and GAS for an arbitraty, but constant input automatically ISS?

Comment: What are you assuming about your system?

Comment: Under some continuity assumptions on the vector field, yes,  see for example Lemma 4.6 in Khalil, Nonlinear Analysis. On the other hand you can find interesting counter examples there.

Edit: Ah sorry, I meant under the assumtpion of $0$-GAS under the identically $0$ input. What do you exactely mean with ''GAS for all constant $u$''?

Comment: I mean, that for an arbitrary, but constant u the system is GAS.

Comment: I think we should reopen this question. It is short but clear (IMO).

Comment: @LCG Even with the new assumption you cannot assume the system is ISS. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is not the case.

First, to state the hypothesis from your question: Given
$$
\dot{x}=f(x,u)\tag{1}
$$
such that $(1)$ is globally asymptotically stable (GAS) for all $u\in \mathbb{R}^m$. Then $(1)$ is input to state stable (ISS).

I claim this is wrong by reusing a well known counterexample from linear time varying (LTV) system analysis:
$$
\begin{align}
\dot{x}_1 &= -x_1 - 5 x_2 \cos(u)^2 + 2.5 x_1 \sin(2 u) \\
\dot{x}_2 &= -x_2 + 5 x_1 \sin(u)^2 - 2.5 x_2 \sin(2 u)
\end{align}\tag{2}
$$

For any $u\in\mathbb{R}$, the system $(2)$ has both its eigenvalues at $-1$, so it is GAS for any (finite) constant $u$. However, take the bounded input
$$
u(t)=2\pi\left(\frac{t}{2\pi} - \left\lfloor\frac{t}{2\pi}\right\rfloor\right) \tag{3}
$$
where $\lfloor\cdot\rfloor$ is the [floor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions). With this input, the system $(2)$ is equivalent to the first example of the *2.2 Examples* section from

*Ilchmann, A., Owens, D. H., & Prätzel-Wolters, D. (1987). Sufficient conditions for stability of linear time-varying systems. Systems & control letters, 9(2), 157-163.*

Note that they cite another paper as the original source for this system, which is page 3 of

*Coppel, W. A. (1978) Dichotomies in Stability Theory. Lecture Notes in Mathematics, Vol. 629, Springer-Verlag, Berlin.*

There, the system is cited as an example of an LTV system that is unstable although for every single $t$ its $A(t)$ matrix is Hurwitz. In the paper they use $u(t)=t$, since they investigate LTV systems, but since the time variable appears only in the trigonometric sine/cosine functions, we can redefine it as a bounded input by $(3)$ and end up with the same dynamical system since $(3)$ is just a sawtooth function with $2\pi$-period.

So although $(2)$ is GAS for every constant $u\in\mathbb{R}$, it is not ISS because it becomes unstable under the bounded input $(3)$.

---

**Edit**: Addressing your updated question. Even if you you additionally assume that your system is bounded-input, bounded-output (BIBO) stable, that doesn't help anything in asserting whether the system is ISS or not.

Consider the system $(2)$ and add a new state equation:
$$
\begin{align}
\dot{x}_1 &= -x_1 - 5 x_2 \cos(u)^2 + 2.5 x_1 \sin(2 u) \\
\dot{x}_2 &= -x_2 + 5 x_1 \sin(u)^2 - 2.5 x_2 \sin(2 u) \\
\dot{x}_3 &= -x_3
\end{align}
$$
with output $y=x_3$. Clearly, this new system is BIBO stable. It is also GAS for every constant $u$ (like before). However, it is not ISS, because the bounded input $(3)$ still makes the norm of the state vector diverge to infinity.